# Multiple Video Playing Simultaneosly PLay only 1 at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

`I have a video slider in my page all videos are in < video > tag in different .
So if i play 1 video and try to play other video both the video are playing same time i neeed to pause or stop the last video and when i play the second or any other video on the same screen. There should be only 1 video play at a time . Like if video 1 is playing when play video 2 video 1 should be pause/stop

```
$('video').on('click', function(e) {
  let vids = $.makeArray($(this).siblings('video'));

  vids.forEach(vid => {
    vid.pause();
    vid.classList.remove('active');
  });

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    this.play();
  } else {
    this.pause();
  }
});
```

i tried this but when i click 1st video its not playing and acive class toggle working. Its not working like how i expected video not pause or active class not removing if i press other video `

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: try to use event.target instead of $(this) inside the event callback, so that you can correctly identify the video element that was actually clicked.

Comment: Issue Fixed. I used event Listener